# Серверный сайт рендеринг Vue js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-cli

1. Мой проект на Vue js
2. в качестве бекенда использую Wordpress

Столкнулся с проблемой в плане Сео, как можно решить проблему с Title, Description для Seo, я так понимаю нужен серверный рендеринг, посмотрел на Nuxt но я так понимаю что в этом случае нужен будет хостинг на Node но я свою сборку Vue использую в качестве темы на Wordpress, как быть?

Есть ли какой способ, чтоб это приложение работало на Php Сервере и при этом рендерила все для СЕО

Comment: Только Nuxt. Иначе только танцы с бубном, и точно нужен сервер, поддерживающий ноду.

Comment: всмысле "хостинг на Node"?  Все можно сделать на одном сервере (хостинге).  Рядом с сервером php, будет крутится сервер NodeJs, задача которого будет стостоять только в отдаче правильных шаблонов

Comment: nuxt и серверный рендеринг, на самом деле, нужны далеко не всем. Оцените, как часто у вас меняются данные которые вы хотите скармливать поисковикам. Если 1-2 раза в месяц - то у вас как раз тот случай, которому Nuxt не нужен от слова совсем. Используйте prerender-spa-plugin и получайте удовольствие.